# Write a query to return parent location base on level

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure like this
location

| id | Name | is_active | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | true | A | null | null | null |
| 2 | A>B | true | A | B | null | null |
| 3 | A>B>C | true | A | B | C | null |
| 4 | A>B>C>D | true | A | B | C | D |

if the given location id = 3 then query should return records have id= (1,2,3) but 4

if the given location id = 2 then the query should return records have id= (1,2) but 2 and 4

if the given location id = 4 then the query should return all records have id= 1,2, 3, and 4

appreciate any help ;)

Comment: _should return location (1,2) but not 2 and 4_?

Comment: * "*but not 3 and 4*"?

Comment: ya, sorry for confusion, I mean location id

Comment: check the numbers, not the names

Comment: So if I understand the matter right you want to always retrieve *exactly one* row, and skip those columns that would contain NULL values?

Comment: The name seems to be *redundant*, by the way – if that pattern is *always* met then you could construct the name from the level columns...

Comment: if I'm in location id=3 (lv1=A, lv2=B, and lv3=C), meaning that I should visit A and B. so that y I'd to returning all records have id = 1, 2, and 3

Comment: Hm... Your database design looks a bit unfortunate to me then. The task would have been easier if you'd identify the other rows by their ids (so 1 instead of A, 2 instead of B, ...).

Comment: ya, I also want to identity record by id but It's a legacy, I can't change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the names:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH id = 3
CONNECT BY name = SUBSTR(PRIOR name, 1, INSTR(PRIOR name, '>', -1) - 1)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH id = 3
CONNECT BY PRIOR name
           = name || '>' || COALESCE(PRIOR level4, PRIOR level3, PRIOR level2)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table_name x
         WHERE  x.name LIKE t.name || '%'
         AND    x.id = 3
       )
```

or you can compare the levels:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table_name x
         WHERE  ( t.level4 = x.level4 OR t.level4 IS NULL )
         AND    ( t.level3 = x.level3 OR t.level3 IS NULL )
         AND    ( t.level2 = x.level2 OR t.level2 IS NULL )
         AND    t.level1 = x.level1
         AND    x.id = 3
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, Name, is_active, level1, level2, level3, level4) AS
SELECT 1, 'A',       'true', 'A', null, null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A>B',     'true', 'A', 'B',  null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A>B>C',   'true', 'A', 'B',  'C',  null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A>B>C>D', 'true', 'A', 'B',  'C',  'D'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A>E',     'true', 'A', 'E',  NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'A>E>C',   'true', 'A', 'E',  'C',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'A>E>C>D', 'true', 'A', 'E',  'C',  'D'  FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| ID | NAME | IS_ACTIVE | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | LEVEL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | true | A | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | A>B | true | A | B | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | A>B>C | true | A | B | C | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y70wE7QP)

Comment: Huh, didn't even know about `connect by` and `prior`... Appears most efficient to me, though need to peek into yet a bit...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Stupid me... Seeing the other answer I get aware that `CONCAT`enating all these `COALESCE`s results results in the `name` anyway, resulting in:

```
SELECT * FROM locations
  WHERE id = referenceId
  OR STARTS_WITH((SELECT name FROM locations WHERE id = referenceId), name)
  OR (SELECT name FROM locations WHERE id = referenceId) LIKE CONCAT(name, '%')
```

Just one of the `OR`s is needed, of course...

---

My approach:

```
SELECT * FROM locations
  WHERE id = referenceId OR
  STARTS_WITH
  (
    (SELECT CONCAT(level1, COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level2), ''), COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level3), '')) FROM locations WHERE id = referenceId),
    name
  )
```

alternatively

```
SELECT * FROM locations
  WHERE id = referenceId OR
    (SELECT CONCAT(level1, COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level2), ''), COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level3), '')) FROM locations WHERE id = referenceId)
    LIKE CONCAT(name, '%')
```

Both working fine ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5CBIG9h_)/[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fgjXlziY)) and currently best that comes to my mind.

Admitted, both require inserting the id into query twice, which might be avoided by a join, but that likely comes more expensive.

If either of doesn't work on your database (tested with postgreSQL only) for any reason here yet my previous attempts:

```
WITH levels AS (
  SELECT
    level1 AS l1,
    CONCAT(level1, COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level2), '')) AS l2,
    CONCAT(level1, COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level2), ''), COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level3), '')) AS l3
  FROM locations WHERE id = referenceId
)
SELECT * FROM locations
  WHERE id = referenceId
  OR name = (SELECT l1 FROM levels)
  OR name = (SELECT l2 FROM levels)
  OR name = (SELECT l3 FROM levels)
)
```

[Works](https://dbfiddle.uk/0MLy-7zK), too, but requires calculating more strings and more comparisons, thus less efficient.

For the case that `WITH` might not be supported I managed to do it this way, too:

```
SELECT * from location WHERE id = referenceId OR name IN
(
    SELECT level1
      FROM location WHERE id = referenceId
  UNION
    SELECT CONCAT(level1, COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level2), ''))
      FROM location WHERE id = referenceId
  UNION
    SELECT CONCAT(level1, COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level2), ''), COALESCE(CONCAT('>', level3), ''))
      FROM location WHERE id = referenceId
)
```

which was my initial attempt – though with all these subqueries it pretty sure can't be too efficient any more...

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the last character in the `Name` indicates the current level, and the character before the last indicates the parent level, you could use the typical way to solve this problem using a recursive query.

```
with cte(id, parent_lvl, current_lvl) as
(
  select id, substr(reverse(name), 3, 1) parent_lvl, substr(name, -1) current_lvl
  from tbl
  where id = 3
  union all
  select t.id, substr(reverse(t.name), 3, 1), substr(t.name, -1)
  from tbl t join cte c
  on c.parent_lvl = substr(t.name, -1)
)
select id from cte
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/shdB5dkn)