# Write a query to return parent location base on level (p2)

Tags: sql, oracle

At the my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76339970/write-a-query-to-return-parent-location-base-on-level), I can solve how to fetch the location hierarchy. But It seems I have another issue when try to integrate with the system

so I have 2 tables like

location (~20k records)

| id | Name | is_active | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | true | A | null | null | null |
| 2 | A>B | true | A | B | null | null |
| 3 | A>B>C | true | A | B | C | null |
| 4 | A>B>C>D | true | A | B | C | D |
| 5 | X | true | X | null | null | null |

log (~5m records)

| id | Name | location_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | log 001 | 3 |
| 2 | log 002 | 5 |

So the goal is I would like to fetch the location hierarchy which has log only.
The problem is when I try to join with the log table, It has a performance issue. The query seems to take 10+ minutes

Here is how my query looks like [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/y-M3tYr5)
I'm trying this query

```
SELECT *
FROM   location
START WITH id IN (SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM log_response)
CONNECT BY PRIOR name
           = name || '>' || COALESCE(PRIOR level4, PRIOR level3, PRIOR level2)
ORDER BY NAME
```

or

```
WITH cte(location_id) AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT location_id FROM log_response
)
SELECT *
FROM   location
START WITH id IN (SELECT location_id FROM cte)
CONNECT BY PRIOR name
           = name || '>' || COALESCE(PRIOR level4, PRIOR level3, PRIOR level2)
ORDER BY NAME
```

p/s The expectation of the query on the above example should return the location have id in (1,2,3,5)

| id | Name | is_active | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | true | A | null | null | null |
| 2 | A>B | true | A | B | null | null |
| 3 | A>B>C | true | A | B | C | null |
| 5 | X | true | X | null | null | null |

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explicitly update your post with the query having the inner join that you tried, and the expected output, formatted as a table?

Comment: Ya, I tried with INNER JOIN but It seems Inner join will filter out parent's locations, so I try to use sub_query instead of using inner/left/right join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` (rather than `IN` and `DISTINCT`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   location l
START WITH EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM log WHERE location_id = l.id)
CONNECT BY name = SUBSTR(PRIOR name, 1, INSTR(PRIOR name, '>', -1) - 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE location (id, Name, is_active, level1, level2, level3, level4) AS
SELECT 1, 'A',       'true', 'A', null, null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A>B',     'true', 'A', 'B',  null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A>B>C',   'true', 'A', 'B',  'C',  null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A>B>C>D', 'true', 'A', 'B',  'C',  'D'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'X',       'true', 'X', null, null, null FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE log (id, Name, location_id) AS
SELECT 1, 'log 001', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'log 002', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | IS_ACTIVE | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | LEVEL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A>B>C | true | A | B | C | *null* |
| 2 | A>B | true | A | B | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | A | true | A | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | X | true | X | *null* | *null* | *null* |

Or:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   location l
START WITH EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM log WHERE location_id = l.id)
CONNECT BY 
       PRIOR level1 = level1
AND    (  (   level2 IS NULL AND level3 IS NULL AND level4 IS NULL
          AND PRIOR level2 IS NOT NULL AND PRIOR level3 IS NULL AND PRIOR level4 IS NULL
          )
          OR (   PRIOR level2 = level2
             AND ( (   level3 IS NULL AND level4 IS NULL
                   AND PRIOR level3 IS NOT NULL AND PRIOR level4 IS NULL
                   )
                 OR (   PRIOR level3 = level3
                    AND level4 IS NULL AND PRIOR level4 IS NOT NULL
                    )
                 )
              )
      )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Aj0wtqw8)

Comment: I'm thinking is it possible to change this clause to use level1->level4 column instead, so DB can use indexing on these columns
`CONNECT BY name = SUBSTR(PRIOR name, 1, INSTR(PRIOR name, '>', -1) - 1)`
WDYT @MTO?

Comment: The query took 1 minute when I applied the EXITS instead IN

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/9Nn_RLFJ is returning duplicate locations also

Comment: @RonyNguyen You told it to start with 5, 3, and 2 and it started the hierarchy with 5, 3 and 2. It just happens that 3 and 2 have overlapping hierarchies so you will get them in both paths; you did not specify that there was a requirement to only get each row once. If you only want unique rows than use `DISTINCT` on the output (don't use it on the `STARTS WITH` sub-query as you will be trying to find the distinct values in 5million rows).

Comment: Of course you can write the query connecting the `levelN` columns; however, the logic is complex and difficult to understand and maintain; you would be better to redesign your tables.